# Are World Slots in Minecraft Bedrock Realms completely isolated from each other?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, achievements, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms, minecraft-behavior-packs

Are world slots in Realms for Minecraft Bedrock completely isolated from each other, in that one slot can have a world with achievements enabled and no behavior packs, and another slot has a second world with achievements disabled and has behavior packs installed? Or will installing behavior packs disable achievements for all slots?

Answer (score 1):

They are in fact completely disconnected from each other.

You can store three completely different maps in those three slots, and they will all retain their settings if you change the settings of a different slot.